# matlab code for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

Can someone please shed some light about this particular for loop in matlab C ? Initial is equal to each other !

```
for(ir = ir; ir<=temp; ir++){
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ir` is an integer, then the loop essentially does `ir = max(ir, ceil(temp))`